# Is it possible to associate an UpdateProgress with many UpdatePanel but not all?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel, updateprogress

I have 3 `UpdatePanels` on my page, and 1 `UpdateProgress`. I would like it to be associated with 2 of the `UpdatePanels` but not the third one. The `AssociatedUpdatePanelID` property only allows for 1 ID. So,It's one or all of them. Is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is right now, you cant do that.

well in fact there is a way, but you will have to do a lot of work to do it...

http://vincexu.blogspot.com/2008/10/how-to-make-modalupdate-progress-bar-on.html

you will find a script in this, the problem is that you will have to decide to show of now show the progress depending of the e.get_postBackElement().id. control by control...

Comment: Ok, that's what I was afraid of.

Answer (score -1):

just leave the AssociatedUpdatePanelID blank

Comment: In that case the UpdateProgress is associated with ALL UpdatePanels on the page, which is not what I want.